# CDI-Interceptor: Get param from intercepted Method

Tags: java, cdi

I have a interface

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface LoggingInterceptorBinding {

}
```

and a class:

```
@LoggingInterceptorBinding
@Interceptor
public class LoggingInterceptor implements Serializable {

@AroundInvoke
public Object onMethodCall(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    try {
        System.out.println("Log before Method");
        return context.proceed();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Log after Method");
    }

}
```

and a annotated method:

```
@LoggingInterceptorBinding
public void sayHello(String name)
```

Is it possible to get the parameter "name" from sayHello in the interceptors "onMethodCalls"-method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`InvocationContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html#getParameters%28%29) interface has a [`getParameters()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html#getParameters%28%29) method that

> Returns the parameter values that will be passed to the method of the
>   target class. If setParameters() has been called, getParameters()
>   returns the values to which the parameters have been set.